# Google Authentication Token return doesn't contain refresh_token

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I write an example about google api using. [Google NodeJS Client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/). I have followed the instruction set `access_type : 'offline'`, however the object return doesn't contains `refresh_token`.

My Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var Session = require('express-session');
var google = require('googleapis');
var plus = google.plus('v1');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const ClientId = "251872680446-rvkcvm5mjn1ps32iabf4i2611hcg086e.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const ClientSecret = "F1qG9fFS-QwcrEfZbT8VmUnx";
const RedirectionUrl = "http://localhost:8081/oauthCallback";

var app = express();
app.use(Session({
    secret: 'raysources-secret-19890913007',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

function getOAuthClient () {
    return new OAuth2(ClientId ,  ClientSecret, RedirectionUrl);
}

function getAuthUrl () {
    var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient();
    // generate a url that asks permissions for Google+ and Google Calendar scopes
    var scopes = [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
    ];

    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: scopes // If you only need one scope you can pass it as string
    });

    return url;
}

app.use("/oauthCallback", function (req, res) {
    var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient();
    var session = req.session;
    var code = req.query.code;
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
        console.log("tokens : ", tokens); 
          // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
          if(!err) {
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
            session["tokens"]=tokens;
            res.send(`
                <html>
                <body>
                    <h3>Login successful!!</h3>
                    <a href="/details">Go to details page</a>
                <body>
                <html>
            `);
          }
          else{
            res.send(`
                <html>
                <body>
                    <h3>Login failed!!</h3>
                </body>
                </html>
            `);
          }
    });
});

app.use("/details", function (req, res) {
    var oauth2Client = getOAuthClient();
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(req.session["tokens"]);

    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        plus.people.get({ userId: 'me', auth: oauth2Client }, function(err, response) {
            console.log("response : " , response);
            resolve(response || err);
        });
    }).then(function (data) {
        res.send(`<html><body>
            <img src=${data.image.url} />
            <h3>Hello ${data.displayName}</h3>
            </body>
            </html>
        `);
    })
});

app.use("/", function (req, res) {
    var url = getAuthUrl();
    res.send(`
        <html>
        <body>
<h1>Authentication using google oAuth</h1>
        <a href=${url}>Login</a>
        </body>
        </html>
    `)
});


var port = 8081;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('listening', function () {
    console.log(`listening to ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I don't understand. Actually I use this piece of code http://voidcanvas.com/googles-oauth-api-node-js/ . Can you help me fix that ?

Comment: There is no error. Follow https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/ when use set access_type: 'offline' in generateAuthUrl the token return will contain refresh_token, but i set and it not work.

Comment: You can check line 30 on http://voidcanvas.com/googles-oauth-api-node-js/

Comment: no, it not my code. Can you fix that ?

Comment: I want return object contain refresh_token. Can you do that ?

Comment: Until you post the code you are having an issue with, you will be hard pressed getting any answers - check line 37

Comment: Hey, I update question with my code. Can you check it again ?

Comment: Wow - that only took 40 minutes! I'm bored now, hopefully someone else will give you help ... P.S. line 37 looks OK

Comment: Line 43 says `Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.` ... it's optional! Maybe that's why you aren't getting it

Comment: // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
  access_type: 'offline', . When you set access_type to offline. return object will contain refresh_token. The guided said that

Comment: @hung.dev please be aware that Stack is NOT a coding service we are not going to fix your code.   We are here to help advice you on how YOU can fix YOUR code.

Answer (score 5):

The refresh token is only sent once the first time user login to your application after approving the scopes you have specified.

**Edit 08/2018** : Using `approval_prompt:'force'` no longer works, you need to use `prompt:'consent'` (check @Alexander's answer)

If you want to get the refresh token each time user login (even if user has already login before and approved the scopes), you have to specify `prompt:'consent'` in `Oauth2Client` configuration :

```
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: scopes,
    prompt : 'consent'
});
```

Note that this will require user to accept the specified scope each time he/she will click on your link to authenticate :

[image]

You can also disable manually the application in your [account permission settings](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions), this will revoke the application and the user will have to accept the scopes again that will trigger the `refresh_token` to be sent the next time you authenticate :

[image]

FYI, if you need to use `access_token` offline, you have to store the `refresh_token` server side, and refresh the access_token with the stored `refresh_token` when you receive status 401 from Google API. So, if you store `refresh_token` as you should, there is actually no need to use `prompt:'consent'` and force user to approve the scopes each time he/she connects to your application.

Answer (score 1):

According the [documentation](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs#handling-token-events) the refresh_token is only returned on the first authorization.

You can remove the permissions manually on: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Also you can force the user to see the [consent](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/750#issuecomment-304521450) screen again by passing &prompt=consent in the authorization URL, just add this parameter:

```
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: scopes,
  prompt: 'consent'
});
```

It worked just fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (Web clients mostly) the refresh token is only sent the first time the user is authenticated.

If you go to [apps connected to your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) remove the app in question.   Then try and authenticated again.   Check and there should now be a refresh token.