# login with passport.js and youtube authentication always shows consent dialog

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, passport.js, youtube-data-api

I used the passport-youtube-v3 module for passport.js and created a login system for my website. Basicly it works, but even after the user created the account and confirmed the consent dialog, at every login after the account selection the user always has to confirm the consent dialog.

Is this intended to be like that? Or how can i avoid that?

Im not sure what code is relevant here because i did it like in the example page from passport-youtube-v3 ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-youtube-v3) . If you need some more information please tell me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [passport-youtube-v3 source code](https://github.com/yanatan16/passport-youtube-v3/blob/master/lib/passport-youtube-v3/strategy.js#L104-L109), the default oauth parameters are using `approval_prompt : 'force'` which will force the user to accept the scopes (consent dialog) for each login (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42737633/2614364))

If you don't want this to happen, you have to override `authorizationParams` field when you instantiate `YoutubeV3Strategy` :

```
var YoutubeV3Strategy = require('passport-youtube-v3').Strategy

passport.use(new YoutubeV3Strategy({
        clientID: YOUTUBE_APP_ID,
        clientSecret: YOUTUBE_APP_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/youtube/callback",
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'],
        authorizationParams: {
            access_type: 'offline'
        }
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    }
));
```

Comment: If i do that, it works with one youtube account, but not with my second one i tested it with. I also took a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps and noticed that "response_type" is required, which i dont see in the code. Is this maybe a track?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I've made [this example](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/51908fcd70872133ed83492b602cf94f) which is using express & mongoose (to store the session).

Comment: Somehow i mixed up 2 API credentials (copy paste error due all the messing around...)since i noticed that mix up and applied your override suggestion it works!

Im still wondering why this is not default? It looks more convenient to me.

Comment: Strange that this [passport-youtube-v3 library](https://github.com/yanatan16/passport-youtube-v3) has defined `approval_prompt : 'force'` as default (I guess it was for test purpose). If you take this [passport-google-oauth library](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth), it doesn't have it as default param. See [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/64bf4bf1df8a4ba63301cfa202163c90) for [passport-google-oauth library](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth)